# Role in Cycle ORM

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

In cycle orm docs some mappings have such thing as `role`. Text states that is it entity role (well, not informative at all). What does that mean and why do we need this roles stuff? Doctrine ORM for instance doesn't have such thing.

Comment: My limited understanding is that “role” serves as an alias for repository lookup, and I think it is also used when naming a join table/column.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat role as alias to class name in Doctine. Unlike Doctrine Cycle ORM can map any type of objects, including StdClass or custom models. In order to identify mapping between same class instances it uses roles.